# Mezzanine ignores the view, displays the template but does not pass the context

Tags: django, mezzanine

I created a view for my model, with the corresponding urls and template files. Then, in the admin panel, I have created a Rich text page, specifying the same URL (ingredients) defined in urlpatterns. Mezzanine ignores the view, displays the template but does not pass the context.
How can I solve it?

These are the codes:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from mezzanine.pages.models import Page
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class Ingredient(Page):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    information = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_("Description"))
```

**views.py**

```
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse
from .models import Ingredient

def ingredients(request):
    ingredients = Ingredient.objects.all().order_by('name')
    templates = ["pages/ingredients.html"]
    return TemplateResponse(request, templates, {'ingredients':ingredients})
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import ingredients

urlpatterns = [
    url("^$", ingredients, name="ingredients"),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

TemplateResponse does not expect the request in its arguments. See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/template-response/#methods).

```
 return TemplateResponse(templates, {'ingredients':ingredients})
```

However I expect you meant to use the standard `render` function there:

```
return render(request, "pages/ingredients.html", {'ingredients':ingredients})
```

Comment: Then I took a look at the blog and gallery applications and, seeing that they use TemplateResponse, I wanted to try. The fact is that it does not work, in one way or the other.
This was the code I had written using render:

`from django.shortcuts import render`

`from .models import Ingredient`

`def ingredients(request):`

`ingredients = Ingredient.objects.all().order_by('name')`

`return render(request, 'pages/ingredients.html', {'ingredients': ingredients})`

Comment: Are you sure that the correct view is being used? I would actually have expected your initial attempt to give an error.

Comment: I'm back to the version with render, I do not receive any error. I'm sure the view does not run, but I do not know why? Mezzanine behaves as if the view did not exist, I do not think there are any problems with the code, otherwise django would give error. May be a configuration or structure problem, but I have no idea what it might be.

Comment: Presumably a URL issue. Where is that urls.py included? Exactly what URL are you going to?

Comment: I'I answer your question for the two tests I have done. In the first case, my app is inside my project apps folder, then the urls.py file is inside my app folder `project_folder/apps/my_app_folder/urls.py`. In the second case I removed my application from the project folder and included it inside the mezzanine, as a mezzanine app, at the same level of blog, gallery, etc. so the urls.py path is `mezzanine/my_app_folder/urls.py`. In neither case does it work.

Comment: in both cases the custom content type (ingredient) works fine, I can create new pages whis this content type, the pages can be viewed on the site, etc. It means that Mezzanine interprets models.py, admin.py and the template for the custom content type. Only the view for list all page of my content type is ignored.

Comment: Ok, unquestionably is an url problem, in the second test, where I include my application inside the mezzanine folder, I have added my urls `url(r'^ingredients/', include("mezzanine.ingredients.urls")),` to the mezzanine/urls.py urlpattern and it has worked.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the solution has been define my app urls before any other definition in my project urls.py file.

**project_name/project_name/urls.py**

```
# Add the urlpatterns for any custom Django applications here.
# You can also change the ``home`` view to add your own functionality
# to the project's homepage.

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^ingredients/', include("apps.ingredients.urls")),
]

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    # Change the admin prefix here to use an alternate URL for the
    # admin interface, which would be marginally more secure.
    url("^admin/", include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```